# d3.js Tree: Clickable hyperlinks in tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm new to Javascript in general and to d3.js in particular. I'm creating a process diagram by using d3.js' tree vizualisation.

I've managed to get most of everything working and have tooltips display when the cursor hovers above a node. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way for the tooltip to stay visible long enough for a user to click on it. Whenever the cursor stops hovering above the node, the tooltip dissapears.

Can someone give me a hand with having clickable hyperlinks in my tooltips?

Here are links to my bl.ocks and jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mgcarrenard/aLgmksr0/
http://bl.ocks.org/GaetanCarrenard/78be307eb06acd617883e97ad2a79dec

```js
// ************** Generate the tree diagram   *****************
　　
//Calculate total nodes, max label length
var totalNodes = 0;
var maxLabelLength = 0;　
//Panning variables
var panSpeed = 200;
var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging
　　
//Padding for Network
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 2500 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 1400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;　
//Timer for duration
var i = 0,
  duration = 750;　
//Root of the tree
var root;　
//size of the diagram
var viewerWidth = $(document).width();
var viewerHeight = $(document).height();　
//Tree layout. Assigns and calculates the data required for the nodes and links for the tree
var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([viewerHeight, viewerWidth]);　　
//Declares variable that will draw the lines between nodes (define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.)
//Swap d.x and d.y to make tree horizontal [1/2]
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) {
  return [d.y, d.x];
});　　　
// load the external data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GaetanCarrenard/78be307eb06acd617883e97ad2a79dec/raw/b6d51331ecad8a060f22b9a6a4393b88a7b0ddcb/treeData.csv", function(error, data) {　
  if (error) throw error;　
  // *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
  // create a name: node map
  var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.name] = node;
    return map;
  }, {});　
  // create the tree array
  var treeData = [];
  data.forEach(function(node) {
    // add to parent
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
    if (parent) {
      // create child array if it doesn't exist
      (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
      // add node to child array
      .push(node);
    } else {
      // parent is null or missing
      treeData.push(node);
    }
  });　
  root = treeData[0];
  root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
  root.y0 = viewerWidth / 2;

  //collapse all the nodes by default when page is opened
  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }　　
  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  //collapse(root);

  update(root);
  centerNode(root);
});　
//d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
　　
//A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all nodes
　
function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
  if (!parent) return;　
  visitFn(parent);　
  var children = childrenFn(parent);
  if (children) {
    var count = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
    }　
  }　
}　　
// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(root, function(d) {
  totalNodes++;
  maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);　
}, function(d) {
  return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
});　　
// Pan function
　
function pan(domNode, direction) {
  var speed = panSpeed;
  if (panTimer) {
    clearTimeout(panTimer);
    translateCoords = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform"));
    if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
      translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0] - speed;
      translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
    } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
      translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
      translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1] - speed;
    }
    scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
    scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
    scale = zoomListener.scale();
    svgGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
    d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
    zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
    zoomListener.translate([translateX, translateY]);
    panTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      pan(domNode, speed, direction);
    }, 50);
  }
}　
// Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree
　
function zoom() {
  svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}　
// define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);　
//Define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
//Appends SVG working area to the div with the class ".chart", gives height and width,
var baseSvg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", viewerWidth)
  .attr("height", viewerHeight)
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .call(zoomListener);

　
//Moves the SVG canvas with the margins set earlier
//Creates group elements "g" which contains all the objects (nodes/links/text etc)
var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");
//.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
　　
centerNode(root);　　　　　　
function update(source) {　
  //Runs the tree layout, returning the array of nodes associated with the specified root node
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    //Given the specified array of nodes, such as those returned by nodes,
    //returns an array of objects representing the links from parent to child for each node.
    links = tree.links(nodes);　
  // //Spacing for each node. Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 275;
  });　
  //Declare node variable, so that each node has its own unique ID
  var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });　　
  //Declares nodeEnter to the action of appending a node a particular position
  //Swap d.x and d.y to make it horizontal [2/2]
  //Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    // add tool tip 
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(
          //"Index: ".bold() + d.name + "<br/>" +  "<br/>" +
          //"Name: ".bold() + d.LABEL + "<br/>" +  "<br/>" +
          "Description: ".bold() + "<br/>" + d.DESCRIPTION + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
          "Lead: ".bold() + d.LEAD + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
          "Participants: ".bold() + "<br/>" + d.PARTICIPANTS.split(";").join("<br/>")
        )
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });　
  //Appends circle to each node; radius 10, white fill
  //Other attributes of nodes can be appended (color,level,etc)
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.LINE;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });　　

  //Appends text to each node; sets distance away text is
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    //Calculate y-location of text, where if it has children, make it -15, else make it +15
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -5 : -4;
    })
    //Calculate x-location of text, where if it has children, make it +15, else make it -15
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -15 : 15;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    //Where to source the text from
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.LABEL;
    })
    //Text styling
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);　
  //Associate rectangular label to node
  nodeEnter
    .append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.LINK;
    })
    .attr("xlink:show", function(d) {
      return d.LINK_TYPE;
    })
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "clickable")
    .attr("y", -15)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? d.POSITION1 : d.POSITION2;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return d.LABEL.length * 7.3;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return d.HEIGHT;
    })
    .style("fill", "lightsteelblue")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6) // set to 1e-6 to hide  
  ;　　
  //add the tool tip
  var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip") //apply the "tooltip" class
    .style("opacity", 0); // set the opacity to 0

  　
  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });　
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });　
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);　
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y +
        "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();　
  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);　
  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);　
  // //Draws links(edges) to nodes
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });　
  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.target.LINE;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });　
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);　
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();　
  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}　
// Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of data
　
function centerNode(source) {
  scale = zoomListener.scale();
  x = -source.y0;
  y = -source.x0;
  x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 3.1;
  y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  zoomListener.scale(scale);
  zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
}　　　
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;

  }　
  //If the node has a parent, then collapse it's child nodes
  //except for this clicked node
  　
  if (d.parent) {
    d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
      if (d !== element) {
        if (element.children) {
          element._children = element.children;
          element.children = null;
        }

      }
    });

  }　　　
  centerNode(d);　
  update(d);
}
```

```css
<style type="text/css"> .node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>




<title>P3 Operating Model - Process Tree</title>
<!-- load the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<!-- load the jquery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>





<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="p3_tree.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You're using transition timer with duration=750 (around line#19 in code), which causes less time for user to see the tooltip. You might want to increase it.

Comment: Good suggestion! I tried that and it does indeed make the link useable.